# How to get swiss quotation marks for a html website with rmarkdown/quarto

Tags: html, quarto, lang

I try to get swiss quotation marks («text») in a markdown (quarto) document.

My _quarto.yml looks like that:

```
project:
  title: "quotes"

book: 
  chapters: 
    - index.qmd
  
format: 
  html:
    lang: de-CH
    css: style.css
```

The styles.css like that:

```
html[lang="de-CH"] q {
  quotes: '«' '»' '‹' '›';
}
```

The index.qmd looks like this:

```
# Quotation Test

"Quotation please!"
```

But after rendering it looks always like this

[image]

I have tried it with:

- only: `q {quotes: '«' '»' '‹' '›';}` in the styles.css,
- lang: with and without quotes in the yaml,
- and using only de instead of de-CH

I always get the english quotation marks.

Comment: Why not using the html `q` tag? It works if you use `q` tag.

Comment: @Martin thank you, but unfortunately does not work

Comment: @shafee I also need to render the entire report as a LaTeX-PDF. That's where the quotation marks work.

Comment: So in pdf, you also need the swiss quotation?

Comment: Yup, but i managed to do it.

Comment: @BenjaminFretwurst, I would like to know how : )

Comment: @shafee
in the _qarto.yml 
format:
   pdf: 
   csquotes: true

and in the template.tex \usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}

Comment: If you figured it out for your self, then add an answer, or close the question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delpr My question isn't two hours old. I don't have a solution.

Comment: Oh I thought you have solved the problem @BenjaminFretwurst???

Comment: I need to create a report as a PDF and as a web page, so in HTML. In LaTeX I had already solved the problem with the quotes, but not in HTML format. 
Julian has posted an ingenious solution in the meantime (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using [pandoc lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/pandoc-quotes.lua/man/pandoc-quotes.lua.md) for quotations. The raw code for the filter can be found [here](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/blob/master/pandoc-quotes.lua/pandoc-quotes.lua) (you have to copy that code into a newly created file in your project called **pandoc-quotation.lua**).

```
---
format: html
filters: [pandoc-quotation.lua]
quot-lang: de-CH
---

# Quotation Test

"Quotation please!"

'Small quotation please!'
```

[image]

A full list of potential quotations:

```
    ar          = {'”',  '“',     '’',  '‘'    },
    bs          = {'”',  '”',     '’',  '’'    },
    bo          = {'「', '」',     '『', '』'    },
    bs          = {'”',  '”',     '’',  '’'    },
    cn          = {'「', '」',     '『', '』'    },
    cs          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    cy          = {'‘',  '’',     '“',  '”'    },
    da          = {'»',  '«',     '›',  '‹'    },
    de          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    ['de-CH']   = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    el          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    en          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    ['en-US']   = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    ['en-GB']   = {'‘',  '’',     '“',  '”'    },
    ['en-UK']   = {'‘',  '’',     '“',  '”'    },
    ['en-CA']   = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    eo          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    es          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    et          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    fi          = {'”',  '”',     '’',  '’'    },
    fil         = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    fa          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    fr          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ga          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    gd          = {'‘',  '’',     '“',  '”'    },
    gl          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    he          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    hi          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    hu          = {'„',  '”',     '»',  '«'    },
    hr          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    ia          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    id          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    is          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    it          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    ['it-CH']   = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ja          = {'「', '」',    '『',  '』'    },
    jbo         = {'lu', 'li\'u', 'lu', 'li\'u'},
    ka          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    khb         = {'《', '》',    '〈',  '〉'    },
    kk          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    km          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ko          = {'《', '》',    '〈',  '〉'    },
    ['ko-KR']   = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    lt          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    lv          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    lo          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    nl          = {'„',  '”',     '‚',  '’'    },
    mk          = {'„',  '“',     '’',  '‘'    },
    mn          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    mt          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    no          = {'«',  '»',     '«',  '»'    },
    pl          = {'„',  '”',     '»',  '«'    },
    ps          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    pt          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    ['pt-BR']   = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    rm          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ro          = {'„',  '”',     '«',  '»'    },
    ru          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    sk          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    sl          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    sq          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    sr          = {'„',  '“',     '’',  '’'    },
    sv          = {'”',  '”',     '’',  '’'    },
    tdd         = {'「', '」',    '『',  '』'    },
    ti          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    th          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    thi         = {'「', '」',    '『',  '』'    },
    tr          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ug          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    uk          = {'«',  '»',     '„',  '“'    },
    uz          = {'«',  '»',     '„',  '“'    },
    vi          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    wen         = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    ka          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    khb         = {'《', '》',     '〈', '〉'    },
    kk          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    km          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ko          = {'《', '》',     '〈', '〉'    },
    ['ko-KR']   = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    lt          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    lv          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    lo          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    nl          = {'„',  '”',     '‚',  '’'    },
    mk          = {'„',  '“',     '’',  '‘'    },
    mn          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    mt          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    no          = {'«',  '»',     '«',  '»'    },
    pl          = {'„',  '”',     '»',  '«'    },
    ps          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    pt          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    ['pt-BR']   = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    rm          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ro          = {'„',  '”',     '«',  '»'    },
    ru          = {'«',  '»',     '“',  '”'    },
    sk          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    sl          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    sq          = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    },
    sr          = {'„',  '“',     '’',  '’'    },
    sv          = {'”',  '”',     '’',  '’'    },
    tdd         = {'「', '」',     '『', '』'    },
    ti          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    th          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    thi         = {'「', '」',     '『', '』'    },
    tr          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    ug          = {'«',  '»',     '‹',  '›'    },
    uk          = {'«',  '»',     '„',  '“'    },
    uz          = {'«',  '»',     '„',  '“'    },
    vi          = {'“',  '”',     '‘',  '’'    },
    wen         = {'„',  '“',     '‚',  '‘'    }
```